# How to add a role from mention discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

ok so im making a bot in discord.js and I wanted a way to add a role. Right now I have this

```
let role = message.member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "MyRole");
message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id).roles.add(role);
```

But I was wondering if there was a way I could use an @ mention to get the role. So I can have one cmd for all roles instead of one cmd for each role I want the bot to add

Comment: What have you tried to get this to work with a mention?

Comment: Something like: let role = message.roles.first()

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get a role. One method is what you've listed above, through the role name. The other method is through the ID, which is what I used.

I would first get the ID of the role mentioned in the message, then grab the `role` from that and proceed to add it to the `message.author`

---

Code:

```js
//checks if the user has mentioned any roles
if (message.mentions.roles.size === 0) return message.channel.send("You didn't mention any roles.");
let roleID = message.mentions.roles.first().id;
let role = message.member.guild.roles.cache.get(roleID);
message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id).roles.add(role);
```

Comment: I keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')` , how can I fix this?

Comment: If you're using discord.js v13 then it may have changed. This code is only relevant to discord.js v12.